# How to resolve 'Failed to locate valid civi root' error?

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

I have installed the CiviCRM buildkit using Docker. Then i deleted the docker image and installed the [buildkit](https://github.com/michaelmcandrew/civicrm-buildkit-docker) again using Docker but the installation failed. I have stated the error below

```
+++ '[' '!' -d /buildkit/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin -o '!' -d /buildkit/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM ']'
+++ cvutil_fatal 'Failed to locate valid civi root: /buildkit/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm'
+++ echo 'Failed to locate valid civi root: /buildkit/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm'
Failed to locate valid civi root: /buildkit/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm
+++ exit 90
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I think it's simply likely to mean that civicrm is not installed in your new site. I solved the problem by re-running

`civibuild destroy mysitename`

`civibuild create mysitename --url http://localhost:8080`

My initial install command contained an error which explains why civicrm was not downloaded/installed successfully. Short of doing a manual civicrm install via the CMS, there didn't seem an obvious way to fix a missing component from the buildkit install.

If you're using docker, I think you need to prepend 'docker-compose exec -u buildkit civicrm' to those commands, or login to the docker container.